# Ruby on Rails 3 + Rspec + Capybara: check response status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I migrated from Webrat to Capybara and now i get a lot of errors. For example in webrat i could use that in integration test:

```
response.should be_success
```

But Capybara shows that:

```
Failure/Error: response.should be_success
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `success?' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there any method that provides such function?

**UPD**: My spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Admins" do
  before(:each) do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)

    visit '/'
    click_link "Login"
    fill_in "Email",  :with => @admin.email
    fill_in "Password", :with => 'qwerty'
    click_button "Sign in"
  end

  describe "Admin panel" do
    it "should have correct links" do
      click_link "User"
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're mixing controller and request specs.

In a controller spec you check the `response`, in a request spec, you check the `page` content, since you have only access to the html.

Answer (score 13):

I can't find any indication of shortcuts like a `success?` method, but if your driver supports it, you can do something like this:

```
visit(some_path)
page.status_code.should == 200
```

This was added a while back, but doesn't seem to be well-documented.  Additionally, some drivers simply don't give the information to capybara.  Selenium was mentioned in particular - it'll crash if you try this while using the Selenium driver.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
expect(page).to have_http_status(200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of asset_exists? function in next gist

```
def asset_exists?(src)
  js_script = <<JSS
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '#{src}', true);
  xhr.send();
  JSS

  page.execute_script(js_script)
  status = page.evaluate_script('xhr.status') # get js variable value
  status == 200 || status == 302
end
```

https://gist.github.com/yovasx2/1c767114f2e003474a546c89ab4f90db for more details