# HTTP response 200 with Capybara

Tags: capybara

I try to use several variants to check 200 Ok HTTP response with Capybara, but non of them doesn't work:

```
response.should be_success
page.status.should be(200)
page.response.status.should == 200
```

Is there another one?

Comment: Which driver do you use? Webdriver doesn't support it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails 3 + Rspec + Capybara: check response status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435800/ruby-on-rails-3-rspec-capybara-check-response-status)

Answer (score 14):

I found it:

```
page.status_code.should be 200
```

And it's work fine!!!

Answer (score 11):

Since current RSpec version issues a deprecation warning, I would suggest to change your solution to:

```
expect(page.status_code).to be(200)
```

It works for me.

P.S. The deprecation warning is the following:

> DEPRECATION: Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should`
>   syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the
>   new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` instead.

Comment: Note the [Capybara documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#status_code-instance_method) for this method - it specifies that not all drivers support it, and gives Selenium as an example.

Answer (score 3):

both answers and the asker didnt say which driver they were using. Its an important information, that makes the diference. Just to give a complete information, this **does not work with selenium webdriver**, although it DOES **work with poltergeist and capybara-webkit** drivers

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: to provide a good answer, I have to know which driver the author was using

Answer (score 0):

Selenium annoyingly does not supply any header or HTTP status data, so I wrote this middleware to inject an HTML comment containing the HTTP status code for use with Capybara.

```
module Vydia
  module Middleware
    class InjectHeadersForSelenium

      def initialize(app)
        @app = app
      end

      def call(env)
        @status, @headers, @response = @app.call(env)

        if @headers["Content-Type"] && @headers["Content-Type"].include?("text/html")
          @prepend = "<!-- X-Status-Code=#{@status} -->\n"
          @headers = @headers.merge(
            "Content-Length" => (@headers["Content-Length"].to_i + @prepend.size).to_s
          )
        end

        [@status, @headers, self]
      end

      def each(&block)
        if @prepend
          yield(@prepend)
          @prepend = nil
        end

        @response.each(&block)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

In tests you can get status the code like so:

```
def get_http_status
  begin
    page.driver.status_code
  rescue Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
    matches = /<!-- X-Status-Code=(\d{3}) -->/.match(page.body)
    matches && matches[1] && matches[1].to_i
  end
end

get_http_status
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate way , you could use the Ruby's Http client API to check the response code or type

One way :

```rb
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(current_url))

expect(response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess).to be_truthy
```

Second way :

```rb
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(current_url))

expect(response.code.to_i.eql?(200)).to be_truthy #response.code returns the code as a string
```

PS: You don't need to download any external gem as it comes with the Ruby library